# How to use backspace like functionality in evil-mode to join lines

Tags: evil

I'm new to `evil mode` in emacs. I want to know how to backspace from a line and bring the cursor to the line above.

For example:

```
Mary had a little lamb, 
    little lamb
```

I want to bring the second `little lamb` to the first line and make the text like this
 `Mary had a little lamb, little lamb`

What I'm doing right now is to use <kbd>v</kbd> [visual mode] and <kbd>j</kbd> to the line below and move the beginning of the second line and press <kbd>x</kbd>.

Is there a simpler or correct way to do this?  In emacs I'd just use the  <kbd>backspace</kbd>  to bring the lower line to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jJ` to go one line up and join the two lines together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. [[https://vim.rtorr.com/]](Cheatsheet) has the answer I was looking for. I searched with `backspace` in mind rather than thinking in terms of "joining lines"